# Browser extensions to re-render the page using an updated version of my CSS file, without reloading the page itself

Tags: css, browser-extension

I want to learn Web UI design. (I know, I know. Being a programmer puts me at a disadvantage. But I want to try anyway.) Thus, I would like to "debug" my CSS files.

Once of the biggest annoyances I have found is that I cannot test a change in my CSS files without reloading the whole page. Sometimes, the page is too big. Sometimes, a lot of elements were brought to the page after lots of clicks, because my pages rely too heavily on AJAX. Sometimes, I just hate hitting Command+R all the time.

Is there any extension for any of the major browsers (preferably Safari and/or Chrome) that re-renders the page using an updated version of the CSS file, without reloading the whole page itself?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try the developer tools in chrome, using them you can live edit your css definitions. Although I don't know an extension that allows you to reload only a stylesheet, this might work for you when you want to test only a few changes.
Firebug for Firefox allows the same thing.

Answer (score 1):

The Firefox "Web Developer" plugin allows you to "Add User Style Sheet..." from its menu. It also has an "Edit CSS" feature that lets you live-edit the contents of the css files (for example file1.css and file2.css would have two editor tabs - one for each file) and lets you save the edited file.

I tend to use Firebug more often myself, as Paul suggests, and you can copy+paste the changed css file content from it back into your actual css file.

Answer (score 0):

[Stylebot](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/search/stylebot) extension for Chrome is great too.

You can quickly edit and view your changes. And can actually save this to personally view sites that you can save in a list with edited display from what you modify for the website's default stylesheet.

> Stylebot allows you to quickly manipulate the appearance of any website (using custom CSS). Using Stylebot, you can personalize the look and feel of your favorite websites. It is also a great tool to learn CSS and for debugging your own site's design.